# Export custom model training data in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I am using the example [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-an-object-detector-using-you-only-look-once.html) to train a custom model.
I am training the yolov2 object detector using

```
[detector,info] = trainYOLOv2ObjectDetector(preprocessedTrainingData,lgraph,options);
```

Previously i have created custom yolov5 model in python which results in a .pt file which can be used in future. But in the matlab example here, there is no output file. I have to train the model every time. Is there any way to get the custom trained model file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
detector = trainYOLOv2ObjectDetector(trainingData,checkpoint,options)
```

to resume training from a specific checkpoint. The checkpoint is specified as a *yolov2ObjectDetector* object. This means that you would want to save this checkpoint during your initial training of the YOLOv2 model periodically. To do that specify a  *CheckpointPath* before training.

You can then load the checkpoint like this:

```
data = load('/yourpathtothemodel/checkpath/yolov2_checkpoint__216__2018_11_16__13_34_30.mat');
checkpoint = data.detector;
```

So the initial training of your model should look similar to this:

```
detector = trainYOLOv2ObjectDetector(trainingData,lgraph,options)
```

where *options* is defined before the execution of the training method and has the *CheckpointPath* to your local dictionary:

```
options = trainingOptions('sgdm',...
      'InitialLearnRate',0.001,...
      'Verbose',true,...
      'MiniBatchSize',16,...
      'MaxEpochs',30,...
      'Shuffle','never',...
      'VerboseFrequency',30,...
      'CheckpointPath',"C:\yourpathtothemodel);
```

Comment: @Dev Drone Bhowmik does that answer your question?

Comment: yes, Thanks. There are many files in that folder. The last one is always the latest one ? Also, if i add new images in the dataset can i start the training using the created file? If yes how ? you didnt mentioned it.

Comment: The arguments for the trainingOptions function are default values. I did not check it out put you would probably able to just define 'Checkpoint', your path and nothing else. Fine-tuning also works. This is the syntax to do so: detector = trainYOLOv2ObjectDetector(trainingData,detector,options)